# background-image using php and stored path in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to figure out how to pull out the path (e.g. images/img1.png) from MySQL and echo it into

```
<div class="fullscreen" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $query['image'] ?>');background-position:100% 50%;" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
```

However, the image doesn't get returned and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry for wasting your time.  I just figured it out.  I forgot to select the image in my select statement!

I had SELECT text FROM table rather than SELECT text, image FROM table

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..
`<div class="fullscreen" style="background-image:url('folderpath/<?=$query['image'];?>');background-position:100% 50%;" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">`